# Eclipse cygwin error - make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: eclipse, build-process, cygwin

From today afternoon I am trying to **setup C/C++(cygwin gcc/g++) compiler for Eclipse** Helios in Windows 7 **inorder to run OpenGL applications** in Eclipse(I have already configured Visual Studio 2008 for running OpenGL applications and programs are also running in it), but I'm unable to run a small C program successfully in Eclipse. Till now I have **added gcc/g++ include files and some library files in project properties under C/C++ general->paths and symbols**

They are:

**Includes**

```
C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\3.4.4\include, 
C:\cygwin\usr\include,
C:\cygwin\usr\include\w32api,
C:\cygwin\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\3.4.4\include\c++\backward
```

**Libraries**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\GlU32.Lib,
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\glut32.Lib,
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\opengl32.Lib
```

**Library path**

```
C:\cygwin\lib\w32api
```

***After including all these and with successfully building the program, I'm unable to run the program, which gives me an error***

> "make: *** No rule to make target
>   `all'.  Stop."

How should i solve this problem?

Comment: Is there a file named `Makefile` or `GNUmakefile` in the directory you're executing `make` from?